# Problem on PHP array_diff() function

Tags: php, array-difference

Here this is my code...

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
    $team_id=$_GET['team_id'];
    $sql1=mysql_query("select members from team where team_id='$team_id'");
    $sql=mysql_query("select user_id from users where school_id= '1'"); 

    while($array=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $x[] = $array['user_id'];

        }

    echo "<hr/>";

    foreach($x as $tem){
            echo $tem;
            echo "  ";
    }
    echo "</br>";
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    $member=unserialize($row1['members']);
    echo array_diff_assoc($x ,$member);

    echo "</br>";
        foreach($member as $tem){
                echo $tem;
                echo "  ";
        }
?>
```

and I'm receiving the output as

```
1 5 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
Array
15 16 17 18 19 20
```

I don't know why im recieving like `Array`. I want to receive the different values as

```
1 5 11 12 13 14
```

Comment: You cannot `echo` an array. You will always get `Array` if you `echo` it. For debugging, use `print_r()`. For production, loop over the array and generate appropriate output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach(array_diff_assoc($x ,$member) as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem in merge arrays.. `<?
 include("db.php");
 $mem=$_POST['mem'];
 $member=$_POST['member'];
 $members = array_merge ($member, $mem);

?>`  but an error msg showing  `
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in C:\AppServ\www\teen\ad_team_mem_db.php on line 5`

Comment: You would need to create a new question for this, and if my answer helped you, its customary to click the tick to the left of the answer to mark it as the correct answer for the question.

Comment: this $member value is im passing through hidden value as `echo "<input type='hidden' value='$member' name='member[]'>";`

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff_assoc` returns an array, which you're echoing out. try `print_r()` or `var_dump()` instead of echo to view the array's contents.

Comment: Now I have a problem on Merge 2 Arrays !!

Comment: `<?
 include("db.php");
 $mem=serialize($_POST['mem']);
 $member=serialize($_POST['member']);
 $members = array_merge ($member, $mem);
 foreach($mem as $item)
 {
  echo $item;
 }
?>`

Comment: Why are you serializing the arrays? that turns arrays into strings. you can't 'array merge' strings. Serializing should be the VERY LAST thing you do.

Comment: When I remove the serialize method nw it showing an error that argument 1 s not an array but i have used the array as `echo "<input type='hidden' value='$member' name='member[]'>";         m sending a hidden value here `

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array_diff_assoc($x ,$member));
```